# Chord substituion in Django's Belleville

Tags: composition, analysis

In the lead sheet I have been working from for Django's Belleville, the A section progression is D - Fdim7 - Emin7 - A7.

In most of the backing tracks I can find, the Fdim7 is substituted for a Bmin7 making it a I - vi - ii - V.

Fdim7 having F Ab B D

Bmin7 having B D F# A

My ears like the way either sound, but find the Fdim7 to be much more interesting. I'm having trouble understanding how the Fdim7 is functioning, and the theory behind why it works.

Is it some sort of tritone substitution? I'm only familiar with the tritone sub when it comes to V7 chords.

Thanks!

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fdim7 is enharmonically equivalent to a G#dim7, which functions as a #IVdim7 leading to V7. The V7 is delayed by the IIm7, which is very common. So what you basically have is

`I - #IVdim7 - V7 (via IIm7)`

There are many examples where the I chord in that progression is replaced by the III chord resulting in a chromatically descending bass line:

`F#m7 - Fdim7 - Em7 - A7 - D`

You could as well use a D/F# instead of the F#m7. But in any case, concerning its function, the diminished chord is a #IV borrowed from the melodic minor scale (otherwise you wouldn't get the note 'F').